# How to access definition in interface from a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this interface that regroup some states

```js
export interface ScanFiltersStatePage1 {
  keywords: SensitiveInfoFileKeywordFilter
  categories: string[]
  classifications: string[]
  fileTypes: string[]
  infotypes: string[]
  regulations: string[]
  dateCreated: TimeFrame[]
  dateModified: TimeFrame[]
  likelihoods: LikelihoodLabelType[]
}

export interface ScanFiltersStatePage2 {
  search: string
  fileTypes: string[]
  fileCategories: string[]
  dateCreated: TimeFrame[]
  dateModified: TimeFrame[]
}

export interface ScanFiltersStatePage3 extends SearchKeywordFileFilterValues {
  keywords: KeywordFileKeywordFilter
  dateCreated: TimeFrame[]
  dateModified: TimeFrame[]
}

export interface ScanFiltersState {
  page1: ScanFiltersStatePage1
  page2: ScanFiltersStatePage2
  page3: ScanFiltersStatePage3
}
```

I would like to type a function return with the good page interface

```js
const MyFunction = <T extends PageWithFilters>(page: T, setDestination: () => void) => {
  const url = 'fake/url'
  const filterValues: ScanFiltersState[T] = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.scanFilters[page],
  )

  function requestPage1(){
    const requestFilters: ScanFiltersStatePage1 = filterValues

    fetch(url, {
      filter: filterValues.prop1
    })
  }

  function requestPage2(){
    const requestFilters: ScanFiltersStatePage2 = filterValues
    
    fetch(url, {
      filter: filterValues.prop2
    })
  }

  function requestPage3(){
    const requestFilters: ScanFiltersStatePage3 = filterValues
    
    fetch(url, {
      filter: filterValues.prop3
    })
  }

  switch(page) {
    case 'page1':
      requestPage1()
    break;
    case 'page2':
      requestPage2()
    break;
    case 'page3':
      requestPage3()
    break;
  }
}
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you for your help

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAysx4BioAbGWAZw0kRgAVEBzaARjQG9g00AHWAew4YC40OAJ5tOPDgCZBI4AF8wUOElSZseQsTIVqdaJJZiuvaUPCj2xjgGYZ5%20YuIr0WHPiJxtlaDXrXDlhK2ZhbivAAsdqIKwNAAHhzcsJBoEE4oLuruWuTeAZx6Ampump65uvQMRnqmrhoepOU%20NdV%20gnXZZTrNfg7AkMIc6L7QAOqgkAAWnaRoALxoAOQchYtoAD5LK-SSa5vLetaLIMjc4CQpALLCuACu4MiQoGfzaAA8ACpo8TDgACYkNAjcZTGYkAB8AApttBBB8ADRoEjQSAAEWgFwglGe4EEkIAlPNwWgAG7cUB-QlzYmsdinc4pW6wAivRZIADW0AA9EyCMc6WcLmh4KVYAA1RAEW4Y9pZUVeGAAbQ%20AF1XrdkRhoARoI8kpCxOxIRdvIIAErcbiQJpU4kmmAAOhIcoaJEVMJV8LE%20JA7Hg90eOLQsGgAEdpRcRgwCbT2Gh6UKQ%20GMZAwbKSq6mlHXiKGhKpRjfXH4CjkJNIbzEbG48LRYJc8R8xGHVYqjW5D72DE-QGni8kxHICNJDHDfHBSkBym08V6jlusOc6Km4Wa2OS5AyxXmVWx3667W85Lm1ZJGOO2Ju8Le0Gp5HDqOawnJ2HBzOOvKs4cl0eCyQx%20upblpW%20Q1g2cD1sux4Yi2QTnp2aBXiQADuExbjChLVvGiDIlsqz8HuwavimUYEmOABGIaIOyADcY7YLhBw7IsBE1uwd5DjUZE1pR0DUXRT44egTHQEcrFsRxIzWNxca8fxl4OEAA)

Comment: Not sure if I catching what you're wanting to achieve. If the input is `page1` are you expecting `ScanFilterStatePage1` that is a `type`?

Comment: That's what I want to do yes!

Comment: I changed for this `const requestFilters = filterValues as ScanFiltersStatePage3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the `page` argument as a generic type, then use that type to index ScanFiltersState:

```
const MyFunction = <T extends keyof ScanFiltersState>(page: T) => {
  const filterValues: ScanFiltersState[T] = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.scanFilters[page],
  )

  return filterValues;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAysx4BioAbGWAZw0kRgAVEBzaARjQG8BfMKOJVTbPQ4mQrU60AEwt2EYt3RYc%20InCGVoNegGZJIaAA8ADgHtYkNNK4o5fRYPKqWwNGn2iGALl4KByuyPoNHZ1ExD3l%20JVJfNWDAl01Q629I4WjNYHZgZENwElMAWQBPXABXcGRIUGy0AF40AB4AFTQ9GHAAExI0AGtoAsN4T3DbFIA%20AAo46A8GgEoakYcnAHoltEgC-QhaNAAjaAJDAHdArJzTeCSANUQCYugSBK8IlRgAbQaAXRq0YpJoDH20HKxjGgScY1yqg8ACVDIZIFE5tUFpCYAA6EiJZ6vSYfAA0gRmICcsGgkGKsHAaAuEWut3uAG50iBTrk0KSSMUiN9CiUyhVsmMAOSTMRCmZMoA)

Edit: After looking at your playground, I see what's the problem - Typescript doesn't have an easy way to know that the variable will have a specific type when the function is run. It could, but it would have to be quite smart to do so.

To help it, I would suggest something like this:

```
  const getFilterValues = <T extends PageWithFilters>(page: T): ScanFiltersState[T] => useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.scanFilters[page],
  )

  function requestPage1(requestFilters: ScanFiltersStatePage1){
    fetch(url, {
      filter: requestFilters.prop1
    })
  }

  switch(page) {
    case 'page1':
      // Now typescript knows that page === 'page1'
      // When we call getFilterValues, T is captured to 'page1', and so getFilterValues returns ScanFiltersStatePage1, which is what requestPage1 expects
      requestPage1(getFilterValues(page))
...
```

[New Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAysx4BioAbGWAZw0kRgAVEBzaARjQG9g00AHWAew4YC40OAJ5tOPDgCZBI4AF8wUOElSZseQsTIVqdaJJZiuvaUPCj2xjgGYZ5%20YuIr0WHPiJxtlaDXrXDlhK2ZhbivAAsdqIKwNAAHhzcsJBoEE4oLuruWuTeAZx6Ampump65uvQMRnqmrhoepOU%20NdV%20gnXZZTrNfg7AkMIc6L7QAOqgkAAWnaRoALxoAOQchYtoAD5LK-SSa5vLetaLIMjc4CQpALLCuACu4MiQoGfzaAAU29CCI%20NTMyQAGjQJGgkAAItALhBKM9wII3gBKeYAPjQADduKAACZIuao1jsU7nFK3WAEV6LJAAa2gAHpSQRjoSzhc0PRIDMAGqIAi3SGvAA8ABU0PEYOAsSQ0D8JtNSqRkR89IIhQj2ll5V4YABtIUAXRRaFuIIw0AI0EeSTeYnYbwu3kEACVuNxIE1caj7TAAHQkDUNEjaz56gFiBEgdjwe6PWFoWDQACOfIuIwYb3jSchHM16pKAaaqYRBPYaHgoOQkzeDKBxZLpflggzyezAe9Viqdbk4fYMUj0aeLybWZGknTieb-1z9Ry3RHRZtpfLler%20Tr8AbcfHWf%20bYkkgXXbEvdL-djQ5ThzHmYuk%20K0663hG1nna6XVbJNYXkY355bWl3vDWAe3ZoMeJAAO4TBWSr0EitZoNgIJbKs-Bfpu16QKmbzslyPLJjB0AIiB7AAEbxogVIANwLoh6AHDsiyoXW7C-iO2GgrhvKQgRRELmR0AUdRda0chfiMWhrGXjh8rclxJA8cRaD8YJR4OEAA)

Comment: It types the `filterValues` as `const filterValues: ScanFiltersStatePage1 | ScanFiltersStatePage2 | ScanFiltersStatePage3` and says `Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'ScanFiltersStatePage1 | ScanFiltersStatePage2 | ScanFiltersStatePage3'.
  Property 'categories' does not exist on type 'ScanFiltersStatePage2'.`

Comment: The Playground I've provided is working correctly - What version of TS are you using? Do you have a playground that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: You're right, your exemple is great and thank you. I underestimate my problem, I added a playground. I upvoted your answer to thank you

Comment: @MikeBoutin I've taken a look at your playground and edited my response - I hope it helps!